# HTTP WSDL is not coming where HTTPS WSDL is coming

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, iis, wsdl

I have .net `webservice` which is exposed to another company as `HTTPS`.Now we want to use the the same webservice in intranet,so i added `http` binding in IIS where `HTTPS` binding is already there .I did it like shown below.Now strange thing is HTTPS WSDL is coming but HTTP,only svc URL will come in browser and If you click wsdl or singlewsdl ,we can see like `Web page cann ot be found`

```
  <serviceBehaviors>
    ...
    <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="true"/>
    ...        
  </serviceBehaviors>
```

I added two `endpoints` and  two  `bindings` , one with `security mode=tranport` and another is `none`

**EDIT**
New finding if i change system name with Ip address in HTTP webservice URL, everything works fine, strange but with system name it is not working